# unable to retrieve json data from assets folder using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**what i want** :  i have a config file where it contains some urls in .json file stored in asset folder now  instead of loading environments.prod or .ts i want to load my json file config and basing on that i want run my application

**what i did**

```
 below is my json file    which i placed  asset folder

{
    "baseUrl": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
    "baseUrl2": "https://reqres.in/api/users"
}
```

now i created a  **ConfigServiceService.ts**  fpr storing config file

```
public _config: Object;

  constructor(public http:Http) { }

  getData(){
    debugger;
    return this.http.get("./assets/config.json").pipe(map(res =>  res.json()));
  }
```

after this i create a  **ServiceProviderService.ts** for calling the service file

configData:any;

```
  constructor(public http:Http,public config:ConfigServiceService) {

   }

  jsonData(){
    debugger;
    return this.configData;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    debugger;
    this.config.getData().subscribe(res =>{
      console.log(res);
      this.configData = res;
    });


  }
```

now i am calling the `app.component.ts`

```
 title = 'sample';
  constructor(public serv :ServiceProviderService){
    this.serv.jsonData();
  }
```

now my issue is i am not able to get the json data and if i am putting the logic which is there is ngoninit in ServiceProviderService.ts file if put it in constructor then i am getting undefined

note : here if there are more that once url then each url is distributed to various seperate service file suppose base1 url for 1 service file ans base2 url for another file how can i achieve that

Comment: What's the version of Angular that you're using?

Comment: I'm using angular 6 and in ts config I made modification for allowing json file

Answer (score 1):

To access the assets folder. Make sure `angular.json` has a reference under

`architect` --> `build` -->`options` to the directory where the file is stored:

```
 "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Comment: Ok but with out putting in angular.json also we can consume I did once  but this time I am.using service for that

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it an absolute url and it should work

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/config.json');
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file?file=src/app/config.service.ts) for your ref.

Comment: the one which u did is right and i already did that what i am trying in first  readjson from config service  --> settings service --> some component  if i do this im getting undefined   please check this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file-5zashx

Answer (score 0):

In Angular only components have lifecycle hooks (like `ngOnInit`, `ngOnDestroy` etc), services haven't. In services you should use their constructor instead.

Comment: There is no OnInit shown in service code of OP. This is not an answer.

Comment: Indeed, my bad.

Comment: @nircraft Actually Mark could have understood it so from the OP sentence: "...i am putting the logic which is there is ngoninit in ServiceProviderService.ts file"